# incoming email bouncing back to sender with "no MX or A records for msn.com" msg

Tags: email

Problem started today. I can send from email account @msn.com but cannot receive incoming email. I did not change any settings on my account. I have tried to send from different accounts but all email to my @msn.com address comes back with the "failed" message and the "no MX or A records for msn.com" message.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a DNS problem on Your sending MTA. Have You tried to send test emails from other providers like Gmail?

```
# host msn.com
msn.com has address 65.55.206.228
msn.com mail is handled by 5 mx3.hotmail.com.
msn.com mail is handled by 5 mx4.hotmail.com.
msn.com mail is handled by 5 mx1.hotmail.com.
msn.com mail is handled by 5 mx2.hotmail.com.

# host -t A msn.com
msn.com has address 65.55.206.228
```

Comment: Microsoft had a huge [DNS failure earlier today](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6778042)